# easy way to track what my users clicks on into a database

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a membership site and I want to track what each user clicks on into a table like this:

```
Table UserClicks:
ID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
user_id int
clicked_on varchar(255)
createdAt timestamp
```

Instead of running a ton of ajax calls each time the user clicks on things, is there a better way of doing this?

I'm working with ga.js in google analytics. Is there a way to send the user id to google analytics?

Maybe this is better suited for node.js? Not sure. Looking for feedback. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at event tracking for google analytics? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide You may also be interested in the In-Page analytics http://analytics.blogspot.ca/2010/10/introducing-in-page-analytics-visual.html

Comment: Thanks Jrod. I'm looking through that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading through a ton of documentation I found that using the _trackEvent function with ga.js, one can pass in an integer to google analytics using the opt_value function parameter. opt_value is an integer.

So what I'm going to do is grab the user id from the session and put it into a hidden input on the page.

Then I'll grab the value of that hidden input in the ga.js file and send it to google analytics as the opt_value parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different questions here. I'll just try to tackle the first.

If simply you're trying to reduce the number of ajax calls, you can keep a running log of mouse clicks on the client side, and only transmit them up to the server when a) a certain time interval has elapsed or b) the `window.onbeforeunload` event is raised.

Comment: Thanks p.s.w.g that's a great solution to keep everything in my control.